# How to split a number and add hyphen in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I want to split all numbers in a column.

number:  `123456789012`

to be  `123-4567890-12`

So I want to add `-` at positions 4 and 10.

I do not want to make new columns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "number",
    F.regexp_replace(F.col("number"), "(\\d{3})(\\d{7})(\\d+)", "$1-$2-$3")
)

df1.show()

#+--------------+
#|        number|
#+--------------+
#|123-4567890-12|
#+--------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You can slice the string using `substring` and combine them with a separator `'-'` using `concat_ws`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'number', 
    F.expr("""
        concat_ws(
            '-',
            substring(number, 1, 3),
            substring(number, 4, 7),
            substring(number, 11, length(number))
       )
    """)
)

df2.show()
+--------------+
|        number|
+--------------+
|123-4567890-12|
+--------------+
```